# RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Tags: python, multithreading

I was making a simple Python game. I was trying to fix the following error:

> RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

I have tried `.cancel()` the timer but that hasn't seem to be working, and I have made a `if` statement to see if the timer `.is_alive` before executing it. The console is throwing the error off at `ball_char = play_timer.start()`.

```
def playball(state):
 batbox = [["@", "@", "@", "@"], ["@", "#", "#", "#", "@"], ["@", "#", "#", "#", "@"], ["@", "#", "#", "#", "@"], ["@", "@", "@", "@"]]
 play = "playing"
 play_timer = Timer(1.0, pitch(batbox))
 end_timer = Timer(6.0, pitch_end(play))
 play_timer.cancel()
 end_timer.cancel()
 pstate = "idle"
 inning = 1
 outs = 0
 pscore =0
 cscore = 0
 strikes = 0
 ball_row = 0
 ball_col = 0
 ball_char = "."
 while play == "playing":
     batbox = [["@", "@", "@", "@"], ["@", "#", "#", "#", "@"], ["@", "#", "#", "#", "@"], ["@", "#", "#", "#", "@"], ["@", "@", "@", "@"]]
     os.system('cls')  # on windows
     os.system('clear') # on linux / os x
     # Playing the game
     print "Press enter to start / hit the pitch"
     print_grid(batbox)
     input = raw_input("")
     pstate = "hitting"
     # Hitting
     if pstate == "hitting":
         ball_row = random_row(batbox) 
         ball_col = random_col(batbox)
         end_timer.start()
         while pstate == "hitting":
             batbox[ball_row][ball_col] = ball_char
             if play_timer.is_alive():
                 play_timer.cancel()
             else:
                 ball_char = play_timer.start()
 else:
     play_timer.cancel()
     end_timer.cancel()
     state = "mainmenue"
     return state
```

Comment: Means exactly what it says. If you want to start multiple threads, create multiple objects. Once you've started a thread once, you can't start it again, *even if it's shut down or exited in the interim* -- create a new Timer object instead. What's the mystery here?

Comment: BTW, in general, a [mcve] would have all the bits that are related to playing a game removed, and would focus *only* on providing the shortest possible code that demonstrates the behavior with Timers/threads you need help with. (Moreover, a proper MCVE will be code that anyone can copy-and-paste to see the problem themselves without any other setup or framework -- imports, setup code, etc -- needed; this isn't runnable as-is, and so is outside that definition).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation for Threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) (of which Timer is a subclass) states:

> start() Start the thread’s activity.
>
> It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the
>   object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.
>
> This method will raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the
>   same thread object.

Even if you cancel a thread (or timer), you still cannot call start() again. You need to create a new thread/timer object or it is an error.

Comment: So could I, redefine `play_timer = Timer(1.0, pitch(batbox))` ? Or do I have to make an entirely new timer?

Comment: @Handge Yes, that code would create a new timer that you could use.